# How to disable mouse or keyboard temporarily, with timeout?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, input-devices

I would like to disable an input device, but without the risk of loosing access to the computer. The device should start working again after some timeout, or when I request it to do using a different input device.

Let's assume I want to clean the mouse or the keyboard. Cleaning often creates unintended input, like wildly moving the mouse pointer or creating random key presses. So I want to deactivate the input from the device, but will want to activate it again later. Otherwise I may have locked myself out from the computer.

If I have a mouse and a keyboard, I can deactivate one of them and may be able to reactivate it using the other - but that may be hard.

And if I have only a mouse or only a keyboard, deactivating it becomes a real problem.

(Assume I can not easily disconnect the hardware, or switch it off.)

Comment: little confused.. only mice and only keyboard? do mean you want to deactivate and activate with each other? I mean when mice is deactivated you would like to be able to activate it with keyboard and vice versa?

Comment: @PRATAP I want to be able to use it with only one device present. (That is common with kiosk systems. They have a trackball instead, because vandalism protected mouses are hard to build.) But even it two devices are present, the other may not be easily used. Like a mouse button hard to reach by keyboard.

Comment: I Just tried it with different keyboard.. It worked as expected. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtgdR.png